# Zsh goes into command mode on unbound key

Tags: zsh, vi-mode

I like vi mode in Zsh, set with `bindkey -v`.
Pressing escape triggers command mode as it should, but it irks me that unbound keychords trigger command mode, for example, Alt+1 and F1.
Any way to stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your terminal sends the same ESC then 1 character sequence when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> as when you press <kbd>Escape</kbd> then <kbd>1</kbd>.

Here you could redefine the `vi-cmd-mode` widget so that if there are pending keys (characters received within `$KEYTIMEOUT` centiseconds after ESC and otherwise not forming a ESC-starting sequence bound to anything), they are discarded and the widget errors out.

```
vi-cmd-mode() {
  local isEsc=1 REPLY
  while (( KEYS_QUEUED_COUNT || PENDING )); do
    isEsc=0
    zle read-command
  done
  ((isEsc)) && zle .$WIDGET
}
zle -N vi-cmd-mode
KEYTIMEOUT=10
```

Here also lowering the KEYTIMEOUT from a default of 40 centiseconds to 10 centiseconds, so that after pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd>, you only have to wait 0.1 second instead of 0.4 before pressing the next key. Your terminal would still likely be able to send both ESC and 1 within 0.1 second of each other when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.